# Error getting show SnackBar AT STARTUP

Tags: dart, flutter

I wrote this code, to get a `[SnakBar][1]` after widget load:

```
@override
initState(){
  super.initState();
        Scaffold.of(_scaffoldContext).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        content: new Text("TGPS & SMS Permissions are required"),
      ));
}
```

But I got this error:

> Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.

I read [this](http://cogitas.net/show-snackbar-flutter/) article, but did not understand how to use it.

Comment: Do you have a Scaffold widget in your app? Scaffold.of looks for a parent widget that is a Scaffold.  If that doesn't exist it won't work

Comment: @JonahWilliams yes I do have a `Scaffold` widget in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to add a key to your `Scaffold` and call `key.currentState.showSnackBar`.

Now in order to handle this once the widget build itself you actually need to hold on for a second to get the required context. Hence I wrap my `_buildSnackBar` method within a `Future.delayed` call to make sure the `build` method got called before the `_buildSnackBar` one.

So what you need to do is something similar to this example:

```
class SnackBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SnackBarExampleState createState() => new _SnackBarExampleState();
}

class _SnackBarExampleState extends State<SnackBarExample> {
 GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> key= new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
 @override
 void initState() {
      new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1))
      .then((_)=>_buildSnackBar()
      );
     super.initState();
   }
   _buildSnackBar (){

     key.currentState.showSnackBar(
       new SnackBar(
         content: new Text("I am your snack bar"),
       )
     );
   }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key:key,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Scaffold.of` uses the provided `context` to look for a parent widget which is a Scaffold.  If that can't be found, then you will get the error above.  Here is an example of how that can happen, and how to fix it.

For example, below it looks like we have a scaffold in the tree right? But the `context` getter in initState points to the current location in the widget tree, of which `Scaffold` is actually a child

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState():
   Scaffold.of(context);
 }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Text('foo'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget tree looks something like this:

```
MyHomePage <- MaterialApp <- Scaffold <- Text
```

Instead, what you should do is create a widget that is a child of the scaffold.  Leaving `MyHomePageState` as it is, except for removing `Scaffold.of`, replace the `body` with another Stateful widget.

```
class MyBodyState extends State<MyBody> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Scaffold.of(context);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ...
}
```

Now your widget tree looks like this:

```
MyHomePage <- MaterialApp <- Scaffold <- MyBody <- Text
```

Since the `MyBody` widget is a child of the `Scaffold`, `Scaffold.of` should be able to find a `Scaffold` instance.